# Razor output @-webkit-keyframes

Tags: c#, razor

How i can output "@-webkit-keyframes" in a razor page?

I have tries so

```
@@-webkit-keyframes progressBar {
        0% {
            width: 0;
        }

        100% {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
```

but seems not to work.
thanks.

Comment: What's the error you're getting? `@@` should work just fine.

Answer (score 24):

Use @@ in front of 'Keyframes' or '-Webkit-..' to make the code work seamlessly.

Here is a dummy piece of code for razor views:

```
    .blinkMan1 {
        animation: blinker 2s linear 0s forwards;
    }

    .blinkMan2 {
        animation: blinker 2s linear 3s forwards;
    }

    .blinkMan3 {
        animation: blinker 2s linear 6s forwards;
    }

    .blinkMan4 {
        animation: blinker 2s linear 9s forwards;
    }


    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    @@-webkit-keyframes blinker {

        to {
            background-color: rgba(115, 242, 203, 0.80);
        }
    }

    /* Standard syntax */
    @@keyframes blinker {

        to {
            background-color: rgba(115, 242, 203, 0.80);
        }
    }
```